# Convergence of the sequence $a_{n+1}=c^{1/2} \cdot (1+a_n)^{1/2}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

How to prove that the sequence $(a_n)$ defined by the recurrence relation
\begin{equation}
a_{n+1}=c^{1/2} \cdot (1+a_n)^{1/2}\quad,\quad a_1=c,
\end{equation}
converges for every $c>0$? For my purposes it is sufficient to show that it is bounded.

Thanks in advance,
Josh

Comment. Actually it is sufficient to show that $a_n$ is bounded, because the sequence can have only one accumulation point (since I assume $c>0$) which can be easily identified.

Comment: Show it is bounded by $c+1$.

Comment: Is it immediate? Or it requires some effort?

Comment: Let me be more clear. I know that the sequence is bounded, but I cannot prove it in two lines, and my intuition tell me that I'm not able to prove that so shortly cause I am missing some obvious estimate.

Comment: couldn't you just solve for $a_{\infty}$ and see what u get out. this is definitly a two liner

Comment: @tired Using this would tell you what the limit is, _assuming it exists_. Unless I misunderstand what you mean, this isn't enough to show that the limit exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's essentially answered in the comment by GEdgar: One can show that $a_n \le c+1$ by induction: If $a_n \le c+1$, then

$$a_{n+1} = c^{1/2} (1+ a_n)^{1/2} \le \sqrt{c(2+c)} \le \frac{c +(2 + c)}{2} = 1+c$$

by the AM-GM inequality.

Comment: Yes! this is exactly what I was missing! Thanks!

Comment: In place of AM-GM, you can do this $$\sqrt{c(2+c)} = \sqrt{c^2+2c} < \sqrt{c^2+2c+1} = \sqrt{(c+1)^2}=c+1$$

Answer (score 0):

$a_2 = c^{1/2}*(1+c)^{1/2},$ hence $c<a_2<c+1$

$a_3 = c^{1/2}*(1+a_2)^{1/2}<c^{1/2}*(1+(1+c))^{1/2}$ & $(c^2+2c)^{1/2}<c+1,$ hence $a_3 < c+1$

$a_3$ has exactly the same condition as $a_2$ --- $a<c+1$ --- so we can do exactly the same thing with $a_3$ to get $a_4$ that we just did with $a_2$ to get $a_3$, and then again with $a_4$ to get $a_5$...